# Short story that takes place off planet, involving sun and rain

Tags: story-identification, ray-bradbury

I read this short story about 20 years ago, and I'd love to find the title and author. This is what I can recall about the story:

- It takes place in a classroom full of kids (around 10 years old?)
- The planet always gets rain
- The kids lock the main character (a girl, I think) in the closet during the very rare occurrence of sunlight and she misses the entire event.

I know it's not much to go on, but I hope it rings a bell for someone!

Comment: I remember that story from 7th grade lit.

Comment: It turns out that there is a song about this short story. I vaguely remembered it from 10-12 years ago. http://www.myspace.com/nyloosemusic/music/songs/song-for-margo-49897030

Comment: There was a short movie adaptation: [Story where a kid misses the window of sunlight](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/12233)

Comment: A very memorable short story, I remembered reading it the moment I read your first few words.

Comment: I've just noticed that Margot is moving back to Earth in a year. So screw all those kids that were mean to her. She's gonna see the sun in a year and they're gonna be under the rain for the next 7

Answer (score 43, accepted):

"[All Summer in a Day](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_Summer_in_a_Day)" by Ray Bradbury. It's been widely anthologised — follow the link from that Wikepedia article for a list, and it also links to an online copy of the story.

Comment: Yes! I had the rain/sun bit backwards :)

Comment: There was also a short film made of this story. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0195517/